# Saving and recalling asp.net form field values - is there a better way?

Tags: asp.net

ASP.Net forms, SQL, C#

I have an app that needs to save the state of text boxes, check boxes, radio buttons, etc.. and then it has to allow recalling of that form's state at some future time.

My current solution is to iterate through all of the input fields and store the field ID and field value in an XML string which is then pushed into nvarchar or text field in a SQL table. The reason I do this is that over time the form can have varying fields on it so I can't dump directly into a known set of fields in a table.

At a future time the user can recall the "state record" and all the fields that still exist are re-populated and any new fields are left blank.

This works pretty well but I was wondering if anyone has accomplished this in a different manner or better way?

The idea for this project is that my users make a number of selections on a page to create a "query" and I want to have a feature where they can recall a previously saved "query".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net persists the controls state in the viewState. This viewState is all you need to keep all your data. Yes, it store a lot more than just the values.

ViewState is kept in an hidden variable in asp.net.

If you write this value to database and force a loadViewState on page load, you will have all your values restored.

The loadViewState function is called by Asp.Net on postback, so in this case, you would have to call it yourself.

Comment: But if the form changes before the viewstate is reloaded (hours, days, months down the road) won't the viewstate be invalid? i.e. new checkboxs are added..

Comment: Yes, it would be invalid. But if you are loading the viewstate yourself, this can be handled. ViewState is a StateBag, having name and value pairs.

Answer (score -2):

It's much easier in client side with for example JQuery, you can save the initial value in a data property of the controls, and refill all you r controls. another way is to make an hidden field and put the initial values separated by a special character, then on each call back (for example a previous values button click event ) read from the hidden field and split your value and update your controls.

Comment: The question mentions a feature for recalling a previously saved query.  That's going to be hard if the application doesn't store the data in some kind of persistent storage.

Comment: instead of saving in XML, i suggested to save in hidden field, so he can even save his xml value in the hidden field.

Comment: Yes the persistent storage is a requirement.